# Android : database not updated

Tags: android, database

I want to update a field in my database, but the changes not saved to database. 
I use The "update" method in database class but not work
Please

This is my Method

```
public void myupdatedb(int id,String value){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("fav", "1");
    mydb.update("contents", cv, "id" + "=" + id  , null);

}
```

and in the MainActivity:

```
db.myupdatedb(1,"1");
```

Comment: Do you get any kind of error?  What happens when you execute that code?

Comment: No.There is no error.just the change not save in database

Comment: What type of object is `mydb` declared to be?

Comment: show us the code for myDb. show us the call of `getContentResolver` if you are using content resolver

Comment: public SQLiteDatabase mydb;...there is

Comment: Store the result of `mydb.update` into a variable and print that out.  According to the docs, that should be the number of rows affected as a result of the query.

Answer (score 1):

From Android documentation

```
public int update (String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

You may include ?s in the where clause, which will be replaced by the values from whereArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.

Try

```
mydb.update("contents", cv, "id = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
```